# pass Global.asax.cs file variable in application start method to my controller asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i created variable in application start method Global.asax.cs file.
i want to pass this variable into my controller.i am new to asp.net. i am  using asp.net mvc4  Razor 
 here is my code global aspx.cs file

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            const string Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPOQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            var random = new Random();
            var result = new string(
                Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, 12)
                    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                    .ToArray());

            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + result);

                     Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

i want to get this path variable to my controller how i accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access variables declared in global.asax file.

Instead of using variable "path" just do like this :

Global.asax :-

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        const string Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPOQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var random = new Random();
        var result = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, 12)
                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                .ToArray());

        Application["Path"] = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + result);  <--------

        Directory.CreateDirectory(Convert.ToString(Application["Path"]));
```

Controller :-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var path1 = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Application["Path"]));  <--------
  return RedirectToAction("About");
}
```

Now `Application["Path"]` can be used anywhere in your entire application.

Comment: when i use this this error come  An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

Comment: that is correct but why  come Access to the path 'E:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tonenew\tonenew\Content\II590F9JYIM2' is denied.

Comment: @srinathmadusanka...i think there can be some security issue while accessing the directory...just check..

Comment: how  can i check  security issue

Comment: @srinathmadusanka...it depends on your system.... just try to google it.... just check path also....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Use Application variable as stated above.

   ```
           or
   ```
2. Declare static variable in Global.asax and access it in controller

   public class MvcApplication:System.Web.HttpApplication

   ```
     {

         public static string path;

      protected void Application_Start()
           {
          AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        const string Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPOQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
         var random = new Random();
         var result = new string(
           Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, 12)
               .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
               .ToArray());

       path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + result);
      Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
           }
      }
   ```

   In your controller

   var path=MvcApplication.path